# How to get JSON using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get the `videoId` from the following JSON data.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/0zJzks-zrF003GuEiUZS95Ot5MM\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "IN",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/yGof-JRWX0o8PNo00I6MyFMMgz8\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "BVwAVbKYYeM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-06-23T15:00:01.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCweOkPb1wVVH0Q0Tlj4a5Pw",
    "title": "[MV] BTS(방탄소년단) _ DOPE(쩔어)",
    "description": "[MV] BTS(방탄소년단) _ DOPE(쩔어) *English subtitles are now available. :D (Please click on 'CC' button or activate 'Interactive Transcript' function) [Notice] ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVwAVbKYYeM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVwAVbKYYeM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVwAVbKYYeM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "1theK (원더케이)",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

My code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("json_file.txt", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("#jqreq").append(field + "<br>");
        });
    });
});
```

And, my output:

> youtube#searchListResponse
>   "uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/tie4n2q9bjwycjkKTqbvbjQ_TqA" CAUQAA IN
>   [object Object] [object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: `result.items[0].id.videoId`. If you just want the `videoId`, what's up with the `$.each` loop?

Comment: it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This script may help you

> json_file.txt

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/0zJzks-zrF003GuEiUZS95Ot5MM\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "IN",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/yGof-JRWX0o8PNo00I6MyFMMgz8\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "BVwAVbKYYeM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-06-23T15:00:01.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCweOkPb1wVVH0Q0Tlj4a5Pw",
    "title": "[MV] BTS(방탄소년단) _ DOPE(쩔어)",
    "description": "[MV] BTS(방탄소년단) _ DOPE(쩔어) *English subtitles are now available. :D (Please click on 'CC' button or activate 'Interactive Transcript' function) [Notice] ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVwAVbKYYeM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVwAVbKYYeM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVwAVbKYYeM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "1theK (원더케이)",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

> parse.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Parse</button>
<div id="jqreq"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("json_file.txt", function(result){

            var videoId = result.items[0].id.videoId ;
            console.log(videoId);
            $("#jqreq").append(videoId);

        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the items key of your result response

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("json_file.txt", function(result){
        $.each(result.items, function(i, field){
            $("#jqreq").append(field.id.videoId + "<br>");
        });
    });
});
```